# Should I use "selbst" or "sogar"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

I am trying to write a sentence similar to the following sentence in German:

> Selbst/Sogar die besten Schwimmer ertrinken können.

In English, my sentence would be:

> Even the best swimmers can drown.

Should I use "selbst" or sogar"?

Comment: Even "auch" would work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference in what both variants express.
But the correct order of words is
Selbst/Sogar die besten Schwimmer **können ertrinken.**